# Can we use same function name in 2 different file in C by giving static?

Tags: c

Can we use same function name in 2 different file in C by giving static?
Like static myfunc() in file1.c and static myfunc() in file2.c.
Will linker understand the scope or it will throw the error?

Comment: Yes, that's ok for the linker, but will probably confuse people reading the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`static` **tells that a function or data element is only known within the scope of the *compilation unit***, *so the answer to your question is Yes you will be able to declare a static function with the same name and **even with the same signature** in two different compilation unit*.

Comment: "with the same signature" is not really applicable/relevant ?

Comment: @PaulR it seems to be what the OP is asking (if I well understood). Anyway edited the answer in a clearer way.

Comment: I don't see any qualification re "same signature" in the question, and it really doesn't matter whether the functions have the same signature or not, of course, so I think it may just be a minor distraction (just my NVHO of course!).

Comment: One nitpick: While the answer is correct, "within the scope of the current compile" should more unambiguously be  "within the scope of the current *compilation unit"* because several compilation units may be compiled in one go, e.g. `gcc a.c b.c c.c`. Oh, and: One should perhaps qualify that statement in general to "`static` *outside a function* ...", because infamously `static` has a different meaning when used in declarations at function scope.

Comment: @PeterSchneider corrected as you suggested since I agree it is better .

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is OK and one of the points of the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Global names declared `static` have *internal linkage*, which means that such a name is private to the translation unit. More specifically, *within* one translation unit, all `static` declarations of a name refer to the same object or function, but in each translation unit, such a declaration refers to a distinct object or function. (By contrast, all names with *external* linkage refer to the same entity across the entire program.)